# "How to connect Docker container with api "

Tags: docker, predictionio

I need to connect to the remote Docker container and send a couple of commands to start PredictionIO services, but from the outside, either via api docker or some of my own. I am new to this, so I have looked in many places, but I have not been able to find something to help me with this, thank you very much.

I was investigating the docker 1.40 api, but without great results.

Comment: The remote Docker API is a massive security disaster if it’s not configured perfectly.  (Anyone who can access the Docker socket can trivially root the system.)  I’d suggest looking into any other way to get containers running on the remote system; automation tools like Chef or Ansible might be a good start.

Comment: thanks, i'll try with one of this options, can you give an example?regards.